# How do I write middleware for Rebus?

Tags: rebus

I want to be able to write custom middleware for Rebus which will wrap around message handlers: executing before and after each handler, regardless of the message type. Is this possible with Rebus, and if so, how do I do that?

Browsing the source code of Rebus, I think it *should* be possible, as the library is very neatly built around the concept of `IPipeline` with customizable "steps". But although it *looks* like it should be easy to add custom steps, I cannot find any public API exposing the pipline. Is this possible to modify the pipeline from the client code?

What I am looking for is essentially an equivalent to MassTransit's `IFilter<>`. We are about to choose between MassTransit and Rebus (or possibly a custom implementation on top of `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`) for a new project, and at this moment this looks like a major feature missing from Rebus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Rebus, you add custom steps by decorating `IPipeline`, which makes it possible to change both incoming and outgoing messages pipelines however you want.

To make it more convenient to inject steps into a specific position in the pipeline, Rebus comes with a `PipelineStepInjector`, which is a decorator that enables positioning the injected step relative to another step.

Check out [the Pipelines section on the wiki page about extensibility](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Extensibility#pipelines) – it shows how an outgoing step can be used to automatically enrich the headers of all outgoing messages.

Incoming steps can be added in a similar manner, only using the `OnReceive` method instead of `OnSend` to add the step:

```cs
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Options(o => {
        o.Decorate<IPipeline>(c =>
        {
            var pipeline = c.Get<IPipeline>();
            var step = new YourIncomingStep();

            return new PipelineStepInjector(pipeline)
                .OnReceive(step, PipelineRelativePosition.Before, typeof(DispatchIncomingMessageStep));
        });
    })
    .Start();
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Sorry, not sure why I missed that when reading the docs.